# How can i get Client IP Address from React App that run on Express.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, reactjs

I use [this](https://github.com/mxstbr/react-boilerplate) react boilerplate. It's running on express web server.

I can get client IP address in JavaScript file [that](https://github.com/mxstbr/react-boilerplate/blob/master/server/middlewares/frontendMiddleware.js#L35) process in server

But I wonder how can I pass that value to React Frontend script?

Please shed me some light.

**UPDATE**
Now, i can use it by using javascript template engine and replace IP before rendering.
Here is the code

```
  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    const ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress;
    fs.readFile(path.join(compiler.outputPath, 'index.html'), (err, file) => {
      if (err) {
        res.sendStatus(404);
      } else {
        const compileStr = Mustache.render(file.toString(), { userIpAddress: ip });
        res.send(compileStr);
      }
    });
  });
```

However, in production, it's using `sendFile()` and i cannot get `fs` module on production :-(

```
const addProdMiddlewares = (app, options) => {
  const publicPath = options.publicPath || '/';
  const outputPath = options.outputPath || path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'build');

  // compression middleware compresses your server responses which makes them
  // smaller (applies also to assets). You can read more about that technique
  // and other good practices on official Express.js docs http://mxs.is/googmy
  app.use(compression());
  app.use(publicPath, express.static(outputPath));

  app.get('*', (req, res) => res.sendFile(path.resolve(outputPath, 'index.html')));
};
```

Comment: you must be making server call to fetch the data, so you can return the ip from server, alternatively you can write cutsom api call which only returns client IP .. check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391979/how-to-get-clients-ip-address-using-javascript-only